# Получить все переменные из класса

Tags: c#, unity3d

С помощью определенной функции получаю все ссылки на классы в нужном `Gameobject`.

Можно ли без перебора с получением каждого класса получить все переменные из этого класса?

Comment: Скорее всего вам это не нужно, опишите свою реальную задачу

Comment: Не знаю доступно ли в юнити, но вообще для такого можно использовать `Type.GetFields` и для полученных полей `FieldInfo.GetValue`

Comment: @АндрейNOP если спрашиваю значит нужно.Получить все переменные и в итоге значение этих переменных

Comment: Я просто пытаюсь вам сказать, что это неправильное использование языка. Заведите коллекцию (словарь) и работайте с ней.

Comment: @АндрейNOP в каждый класс создавать словарь?Мне нужно всего 1 раз с каждого объекта получить все переменные

Comment: Вместо класса используйте словарь, сейчас вы хотите использовать класс не по назначению

Answer (score 4):

Unity3D- это движок для создания игрушек => важна максимальная производительность.

То, что вы описали называется рефлексией, когда объект перебирается по косточкам влоть до того, что вы можете читать и писать в защищенные свойства, что снижает производительность в разы из-за того, что происходит перебор таблиц метаданных, а там идет активная работа со строками.(См. CLR VIA 4.5 от Рихтера).

А потом на страницах STEAM пользователи будут жаловаться, что игра тормозит на CORE I9 и на 1080TI :)

Подозреваю, что вам это не нужно, а нужно что-то другое.

Создайте свойства, которые позволяют читать данные полей и будет вам счастье.

Если вы решаете задачу гибкости, то используйте интерфейсы или внедрение зависимостей.

Comment: я где-то писал,что это будит у всех в клиенте?Это нужно только мне в моем клиенте для разработок

Comment: мне нужно то,что я написал и нечего другого

Comment: Вы не написали зачем вам это нужно. Возможно, есть решение проще.

Comment: получить за раз все переменные и их значения в консоль с каждого скрипта